# How to DELETE an object from a list using Firebase's REST API

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am having a problem deleting an item from a list of objects on Firebase. I have an application that is supposed to create, read, update and delete books using normal CRUD operations. So far I have been able to create and read from the Firebase api. But Deleting is proving difficult.

The documentations are not really helpful when it comes to this issue. Even the answers I found here have not helped.

[image: Here is the image of the data on saved on Firebase]

I have tried the following in trying to delete the second item:

```
const url = `${baseUrl}/-L8X-KCuiwG8n2A1ij0v.json`;

   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     $.ajax({
       type: 'DELETE',
       url: url,
     }).then(function(data) {
       run(null, resolve, data);
     }, function(jqXHR) {
       jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
       run(null, reject, jqXHR);
     });
   });
```

I get a 200 in the response but the data returned is null and the item still remains in the database.

Comment: try const url = '${baseUrl}/L8X-KCuiwG8n2A1ij0v.json';

Comment: that is what I tried above.

Comment: without this - operator

Comment: Nope, that is not doing anything.